# JavaScript Fetch API, for loop stops on an index with a null value

Tags: javascript, loops, null, fetch, continue

I'm trying to figure out a way to move on to the next (i) if a null image src is found. Right now the loops stops when it hits a null img src. Here's the error:

```
"TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'href')"
```

I saw some suggestions to use an if statement with continue, but couldn't get it to work. Looked for a while on stackoverflow and other forums but couldn't find anything that resolved it. Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

```
fetch(`https://real-estate12.p.rapidapi.com/listings/sale?state=CA&city=San%20Francisco&page=1&sort=relevant&type=single-family%2Cmulti-family`, {
        "method": "GET",
        "headers": {
            "x-rapidapi-host": "real-estate12.p.rapidapi.com",
            "x-rapidapi-key": "removingAPIkeyforStackOverflow"
        }
    })
    .then(function (response) {
        return response.json();
    })

    .then(function (data) {     
        houseCardsEl.innerHTML = '';
            
        for (let i = 0; i < 12; i++) {

        if (data.properties[i].primary_photo.href === null) {
            continue;
        }

            houseCardsEl.innerHTML += 
                `<div id="column-${i}" class="column is-one-quarter">
                <div class="card">
                <div class="card-image">
                    <figure id="houseImage" class="image is-4by3">
                    <img src="${data.properties[i].primary_photo.href}" alt="House image ${i}">
                    </figure>
                </div>
                </div>
            </div>`;
        }
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.error(err);
    });
```

Comment: `if (data.properties[i].primary_photo.href === null)` -> `if (properties[i].primary_photo === null)` the error says that you are calling `.href` *on* `null`, not that `.href` *is* null

Comment: @mplungjan Don't you need another conditional after `primary_photo`?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest your slice and test your data:

NOTE: this will skip house image 2 in the display  - you can solve that with a separate counter

We TRY to show 12, but will show as many as there actually are <= 12

```js
const data = { properties: [ 
{primary_photo:{ href: "photo1.jpg"}},
{primary_photo:{ href: "photo2.jpg"}},
{ "noprimary_photo":""},
{primary_photo:{ href: "photo3.jpg"}},
]};
const html = data.properties.slice(0,12).map(({primary_photo},i) => primary_photo ? `<div id="column-${i}" class="column is-one-quarter">
                <div class="card">
                <div class="card-image">
                    <figure id="houseImage" class="image is-4by3">
                    <img src="${data.properties[i].primary_photo.href}" alt="House image ${i}">
                    </figure>
                </div>
                </div>
            </div>` : '').join("")
console.log(html)
```